# How to properly install Microsoft Office in Ubuntu 14.04 with wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine, microsoft-office

I have been trying to install it many times using the Wine version avaliable from the Sofware Center. Is there a proper way to configure it for allowing the installtion?

Comment: Linux is not a drop in replacement for windows. Use Libreoffice and consider updating to a more recent version of Ubuntu, 14.04 is quite long in the tooth. If libreoffice does not do what you need, which is unlikely, use windows, either dual boot or in a VM

Comment: [WIneHQ has 3.0](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) version for trusty. You do not need to upgrade to newer Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 will reach [end-of-life early 2019](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## PlayOnLinux - for Microsoft Office 2010 and higher

I've figured out with a wine GUI called Playonlinux. 
WORKS FOR ANY VERSION OF UBUNTU

It comes with the addequate configuration for multiple applications and games, you have to have only the installer and then follow the program instructions.
[image]

For installing it run the following commands:

To add the repository that contains the program

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key


sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
sudo apt-get update
```

And to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then I installed Microsoft Office Pack 2010 following steps below:

1. Install `winbind` dependency with `sudo apt-get install winbind`
2. Open PlayOnLinux, click *Install*, search for Microsoft Office 2010, browse for *setup.exe* and wait it to finish (on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will download Wine 1.7.52 and dependencies, will create virtual drive as *~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010/*, report success of installation and will create shortcuts).
3. You can access MSO 2010 applications from Dash or other Applications menu.

## WineTricks - for Microsoft Office 2007 and lower

1. Install WineTricks from repository with `sudo apt-get install winetricks`
2. Prepare *OFFICE12.iso* with complete Microsoft Office 2007 installation media, mount it with *Disk Image Mounter* (see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1019952/66509)).
3. Create empty wine-prefix and install MSO 2007 here with:

   ```
   WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro \
   winetricks office2007pro
   ```
4. Wait setup to finish.
5. As the result you will get MSO 2007 installed with shortcuts and file-associations (in my experience PlayOnLinux does not do so with MSO 2007).

Comment: @MadMike: next time you see one of these, just edit it out.

Comment: @fabby okay. Will do.

Comment: Works on 16.04 LTS. Edited your answer to clarify some moments. Thank you!

Comment: Has anyone tried this on 18.04 LTS?

Comment: @Selah I did it over 17, so it may work well over 18.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is PlayOnLinux**
So, I want to first say that the following is not how things should usually be done.
However, after being instructed (on various q&a and tutorials) to download and install the most current versions of wine and playonlinux, and having attempted these methods several times on clean installs of both Xubuntu and Mint, I finally went to the dark side and used the software manager. It worked on both (Mint and Xubuntu), as long as I picked Office 2010 from the list of software on playonlinux (rather than "install program not listed"), and I did it on machines that did not already have either program installed prior to installing from the software manager.
I did get an error that "winbind" was missing. I cancelled the installation, did an apt-get for "winbind", and restarted the install. Everything now works on both machines.
Food for thought: when I tried to install wine and playonlinux manually (cli), and eventually got errors, I tried to uninstall then reinstall from the software manager. This did NOT work. There must have been files left behind that conflicted with the reinstall.