# How to integrate MathType to Microsoft Office 2007 using Wine, winetricks or PlayOnLinux?

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, winetricks

I have installed Microsoft Office 2007 with help of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/998783/66509) using PlayOnLinux and/or WineTricks.

I need to install MathType and integrate it to Microsoft Office 2007.

So I have a question - how to integrate MathType to Microsoft Office Word using Wine, winetricks or PlayOnLinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should select Wine-prefix with installed Microsoft Office (2007 in my case) and install MathType here.

## Using PlayOnLinux

1. Install latest version of from [PlayOnLinux site](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)

   ```
   wget https://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.3.4/PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb
   sudo apt install ./PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb
   ```
2. Open PlayOnLinux

   [image: [![PlayOnLinux with MSO 2007]]
3. Click *Install*, click *Install a non-listed program*
4. In *Manual Installation* wizard select *Edit or update an existing application*:

   [image: install to existing prefix]
5. Click on *Show virtual drives* checkbox:

   [image: virtual drives]
6. Leave checkboxes unchecked

   [image: before installation]
7. Select corresponding arch (32 bits in my case)

   [image: 32 bits]
8. Browse for MathType setup file and click *Next*

   [image: browse]
9. Optionally create shortcut for *Mathtype.exe*.

   [image: Mathtype shortcut]
10. Launch Word 2007 and use MathType as usual.

## Using WineTricks

If you have installed MSO [with `winetricks`](https://askubuntu.com/a/998783/66509) (to prefix *~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro*) you can install MathType here by the following command:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/office2007pro \
wine MathType\ 6.9b.exe
```

---

Result:

[image: MathType panel on ribbon]

---

Notes:

1. currently I have no solution for MSO 2010 and MathType,
   but MSO 2007 and MSO 2013 (with Wine 3.0) works stable.
2. currently *Format Equations* and *Convert Equations* buttons do not work in all MathType version between 6.5 and 6.9, they produce error message ("MathType Error - Too many windows are open"):

   [image: MathType error]

   or "There was an unknown error updating this equation. This equation was not updated. Do you want to  continue?" -

   [image: MathType error 2]
3. MathType 7.4 window does not react on mouse clicks and keyboard.