# How to add another program to an existing Wine prefix with PlayOnLinux?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have installed [Hearthstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearthstone), a digital card game, via PlayOnLinux. Now I would like to install [Innkeeper](https://www.innkeeper.com/), a card manager utility for the game, under the same Wine prefix. Ideally the game and the utility would be launched separately, via separate icons, but run as if installed on the same Windows computer.

How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate MathType to Microsoft Office 2007 using Wine, winetricks or PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043960/how-to-integrate-mathtype-to-microsoft-office-2007-using-wine-winetricks-or-pla) - use this for idea, change paths and program names to needed.