# How to link Mendeley plugin and MS word in Playonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, mendeley, microsoft-word

i want to use Mendeley and MS word 2013 in PlayOnLinux , Is that possible? I installed mendeley in the same virtual drive of MS office, so i manage to install the mendeley plugin for word however it didn't work so far, they refers an error 429. Thank you very much for your help!! Mendeley is a software for reference citations.
[image: First error]

[image: Second Error when press on "Insert Citation option"]

Comment: You have to adapt [my method of MathType installation into Word](https://askubuntu.com/q/1043960/66509) for your case.

Comment: Hi, I am using ubuntu mate 20.04.

Comment: @N0rbert, I followed your method but in both MS word 2010 and 2013, the same message appear: "ActiveX component cant create object (429) in MendeleyPlugin".

Comment: Oh, I see. Looks like they use some kind of VIsualBasic (or related) here, this functionality does not work well on Wine. Try searching on http://appdb.winehq.org/ for solution.